# Subgroup Lattice of Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

> Use the subgroup lattice structure of the symmetries of a square, $Sq$, and use it to find the subgroup lattice of all left cosets of the normal subgroup $\langle r^2\rangle$.

This is a problem from my intro algebra class.

In this case, we begin with the subgroup structure of $Sq$ and consider the normal subgroup generated by $r^2$, where $r$ is rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around the z axis and the square is centered at the origin and lies in the xy plane.
(Don't think it matters, but a, b, c, and d are rotations by $\pi$ around the respective axes x, y, y=-x, and y=x).

My professor's claim was that since $\langle r^2\rangle$ is a normal subgroup, there exists a bijection between $Sq/\langle r^2\rangle$ and subgroups of $Sq$ containing $\langle r^2\rangle$, and thus we can basically preserve the structure of all groups containing $\langle r^2\rangle$, as in the diagrams below.

Can anyone explain the logic behind this? I feel as though we need something more than "there exists a bijection." I don't believe that this bijection would be an isomorphism, since I don't think you could assign a group structure to both $Sq/\langle r^2\rangle$ and $\langle r^2\rangle$.

Thanks.

[image: Subgroup lattices of $Sq$ and $Sq/\lange r^2\rangle$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bijection is not between $Sq/\langle r^2\rangle$ and $\langle r^2\rangle$ but between the set of subgroups of $Sq/\langle r^2\rangle$ and the set of subgroups of $Sq$ "over" (containing) $\langle r^2\rangle$. This is an example of what is called a *lattice morphism*, as it preserves the partial ordering of inclusion.

Comment: thanks; fixed. but why is it that it preserves the ordering of inclusion?

Comment: That's a *good* question...the best answer I can think of is that groups have a certain "uniformity" due to the way group multiplication works, for example-all the cosets "shrink" the same amount when you pass to the quotient, it's not like some cosets shrink a lot, but others just shrink a little bit. "Modding out" by a normal subgroup effectively "collapses" that subgroup to a point: the identity.

Comment: cool. do you know what this theorem is called?